# Controlling Columns using Category Filter in Google VIsualization Dashboard

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Dear fellow developers,

I am trying to create a dashboard for Sales Data of a company store at various location. Source Data is like

```
[["Day", "Location A", "Location B"],
    ["Sun", 1525, 1800],
    ["Mon", 1400, 1300],
    ["Tue", 1800, 1600],
    ["Wed", 1100, 900],
    ["Thu", 1700, 300],
    ["Fri", 900, 1927],
    ["Sat", 1250, 2130]];
```

I am creating an area chart where I can see the previous week sales of all the locations. Additionally, I want a filter where I will select the location. On location selection, chart should show the area chart only for that location.
I am trying to use `CategoryFilter` from Google Visualization Dashboard but have not much success yet.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/fdqtpur0/1/) is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fdqtpur0/1/) which you can check to know where I am upto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fdqtpur0/2/).

Instead of using a `dashboard`, I drew the filter and chart without it and then added a listener for `'statechanges'` on the filter.
When a statechange occurs, it checks what's selected and sets the View of the `chartWrapper` to this, and then redraws the whole thing.

Also added some cosmetics for colors.

A presonal preference is also to specify the max/min value of the chart, so it won't be so "jumpy" when you change the view of it.

Comment: Wow.. Thank you. I was thinking about this approach but I did not know how to add an event listener on a Category Filter. You made my day.